# Value still being read from Shared Preferences even after clearing it

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am storing auth token for a signed in user in `SharedPreferences` and on sign out am clearing the preferences.

```
private void doSignOut(){
    SharedPreferences pref= getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_DIR, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
    boolean isCleared = editor.commit();
    FLog.d("Is Pref cleared = " + isCleared);
    mDbHelper.onUpgrade(mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase(), 0, 0);
    mDbHelper.close();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and then in my `SignInActivity` i check for the `authToken`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
    checkForSignIn();

}

private void checkForSignIn() {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREF_DIR, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String authToken = pref.getString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_AUTH, null);
    if(null == authToken){
         showAnimations();
    } else {
        FLog.d("AuthToken already present " + authToken);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.ribbon.ribbon.MainNavigationActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The problem is that in `checkForSignIn()` authToken is not `null` instead holds the actual value.

I check the preference xml before signing out and it contains the values, while it is being cleared after signout.

What's wrong here? Am I missing something very obvious?
please help.

Comment: where are you clearing these values..?

Comment: btw: it is pointless to call `apply()` and then `commit()`. Stick to just `commit()`.

Comment: @sandy in `doSignOut` third line. 
@WebnetMobile.com yes you are right. have added just to check if commit was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it to work. The problem was the two activities were in different processes (since, I am using multiple `MapView` in my app). It is mentioned in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) that `SharedPreferences` doesn't support use under different processes. So i moved `SignInActivity` and the other one inside same main process and now it works well.

It was a pretty obvious mistake on my side and had to scratch my head for 4 hours on this. So this might help someone in similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.remove(Constants.SHARED_PREF_AUTH);
editor.commit();
```

will do

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the string with null yourself:

```
editor.putString(Constants.SHARED_PREF_AUTH, null);
```